# How to detect which table cell is clicked in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2

I am developing app which users will choose one of the two pictures in one cell. My prototype cell looks like :

[image: prototype cell]

How can I detect when the user presses the vote button which cell is selected ?

My tableView Code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "NewTableViewCell"
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewTableViewCell

        //For left image
        if let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: self.polls[indexPath.row].poll_photo1 ){
            cell.leftImage.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
        }
        //For right image
        if let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: self.polls[indexPath.row].poll_photo2 ){
            cell.rightImage.sd_setImageWithURL(url)

        }

        //For user picture
        if let url:NSURL? = NSURL(string: self.polls[indexPath.row].users[0].user_photo ){
            cell.userPicture.sd_setImageWithURL(url)
        }

        // gets username and text
        cell.userName.text=self.polls[indexPath.row].users[0].user_name
        cell.description.text = self.polls[indexPath.row].poll_textfield

        return cell
    }
```

My web API:

[image]

Comment: How are you handling votes in the first place?

Comment: Looks like it should be handled in the `NewTableViewCell` class.

Comment: I meant in your Swift code, obviously. Or haven't you tried anything yet?

Comment: @tmac99 check my solution. May it help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming that your custom table view cell `NewTableViewCell` is having an outlet for your vote button.
Just tag your `voteButton` with `indexPath.row` and fetch the tag in its target function as shown below. You will get to know which cell's `voteButton` was tapped when you press your Vote Button

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NewTableViewCell") as! NewTableViewCell

    //Tagging with indexPath.row
    cell.voteLeftButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.voteRightButton.tag = indexPath.row


    //This is the latest Swift 2.2 syntax for selector. If you are using the older version of Swift, Kindly check the selector syntax and make changes accordingly
    cell.voteLeftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(voteLeftButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    cell.voteRightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(voteRightButtonPressed), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return cell

}

func voteLeftButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){

    print("Left Button Table cell clicked is \(sender.tag)")

}

func voteRightButtonPressed(sender:UIButton){

    print("Right Button Table cell clicked is \(sender.tag)")

}
```

Comment: I have two button IBAction leftVote and IBAction  rightVote, should I use IBOutlet ? instead of IBAction

Comment: yes, create an `IBOutlet` of both in your custom cell class

Comment: rather creating IBActions, make a target in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just like the solution I posted

Comment: Thanks it is working but I have one more question if I use IBOutlet how will I detect if the right button or left button is pressed ?

Comment: you can make different actions `voteLeftButtonPressed` for left and `voteRightButtonPressed` for right. Check my edit in the solution. If it helps you, kindly tick as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Add target/action to your button in cell configure method like this:

```
 let tap : UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourController.tapAction(_:)))
```

Then implement tapAction method

```
func tapAction(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer)
  {

    if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended
    {
        return

    }
    let btn = sender.view as! UIButton

    let pointTo : CGPoint  = CGRectOffset(btn.bounds, btn.frame.size.width/2, btn.frame.size.height/2).origin;
    let buttonPosition : CGPoint  = btn.convertPoint(pointTo, toView: self.tableView)

    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)


    ...

}
```

Comment: If its a `UIButton`, why we are giving a Tap Gesture to a `UIButton`. `UIButton` itself inherits from `UIControl` and has the capability for various events

Comment: Yes, you are right. My way is just more universal if you want to use to UIImageView for example